# PHP & MySQL: Upon insert, all values are zero, but they shouldn't be

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, insert

SO I'm using PHP and PDO to insert data into a MySQL database.

```
function addLog($id, $wd, $m, $md, $t, $tz, $y, $ilp, $igp)
{
    echo "|2|$wd/$m/$md/$t/$tz/$y/$ilp/$igp|";
    $connection = connectUserLogfiles();
    try
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `log_meta` (`log_id`, `weekday`, `month`, `month_day`, `time`, `time_zone`, `year`, `inside_local_ip`, `inside_global_ip`) VALUES (log_id=:log_id, weekday=:weekday, month=:month, month_day=:month_day, time=:time, time_zone=:time_zone, year=:year, inside_local_ip=:inside_local_ip, inside_global_ip=:inside_global_ip);";

        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':log_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':weekday', $wd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':month', $m, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':month_day', $md, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', $t, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time_zone', $tz, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':year', $y, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':inside_local_ip', $ilp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':inside_global_ip', $igp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->rowCount();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<p>Error: something went wrong in addLog(), and we have absolutely no idea why. Sorry.</p>';
    }
}
```

the result of the echo statement is as follows:

```
|1|Sun/Dec/31/12:12:12/Africa/Abidjan/2015/10.0.0.0/9.0.0.0|
```

Also, a message is displayed which indicates that one row was successfully returned in the Result Set via the `$result` variable. (this occurs in the index, but i assure you, one row is returned in the Result Set.)

My problem is that the database indicates that every column-value in the inserted row has a value of zero. This also goes for the Primary Key, which is NOT auto-incremented, because that is taken care through the use of PHP. (the lack of auto-increment is a result of how this database is tied to an app and how that app functions.)

After this query is executed, the user is taken to a view which correctly displays all of the associated information as the user inputted the data. However, this is based on the local variables from the user input, and not the database. I felt this was safe to do because at that point, i have confirmed that the user input was valid and that it was inserted into the database correctly.

My primary key, the log_id,is an INT data type. 
All other data types are VARCHAR. 
There are NO default values set for the table in the database. 
NONE of the columns are set as requiring unique values within their respective columns. 
NONE of the columns are Foreign Keys. 
ALL of the columns are set as nullable, merely because of my lazyness, and because i've already check for null values before this point in the INSERT process.

WHY does the insert not work correctly? I use PHPMyAdmin to operate with the database

Comment: just in case you are confused, in the echo statement on line 2 of the code, 'Africa/Abidjan' is the contents of the $tz variable. they are not two different variables.

Comment: also, connectUserLogfiles(); operates correctly. I not only use it for other PDO statement functions contained in the same php script file, but even another PDO statement almost exactly like this one which inserts different data into a different table of this database.

Comment: You're using UPDATE/SET syntax in your VALUES. Using exceptions would have thrown that syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the columns from the `VALUES (...)` of your query -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `log_meta` (`log_id`, `weekday`, `month`, `month_day`, `time`, `time_zone`, `year`, `inside_local_ip`, `inside_global_ip`) VALUES (:log_id, :weekday, :month, :month_day, :time, :time_zone, :year, :inside_local_ip, :inside_global_ip);";
```

You already defined them in the query, and since there was not space between the equal sign and semicolon - `=:` your params were not recognized as params.